# FMTONLY in SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

When calling `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`, I can see a bunch of

> SET FMTONLY ON

and

> SET FMTONLY OFF

However https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx says:

> Do not use this feature. This feature has been replaced by
>   sp_describe_first_result_set (Transact-SQL),
>   sp_describe_undeclared_parameters (Transact-SQL),
>   sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (Transact-SQL), and
>   sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object (Transact-SQL).

Is this still the correct .Net method to call for bulk inserts?

Comment: Yes. Actually, there is no other. Which .NET version are you using? SqlBulkCopy targets all SQL Server versions, while FMTONLY was deprecated in 2012

Comment: The use of deprecated features is not an error, and the listed replacements are not a simple drop-in replacement for `FMTONLY`. There is still plenty of code in the wild (including from MS itself) that uses and will continue to use `FMTONLY` for quite a while. The most recent release of SQL Server (2016) still supports it, and given the speed at which deprecation moves in SQL Server, this is not likely to change for years. So don't be surprised that `SqlBulkCopy` contains no special case code for 2012 onwards.